# Help with simplifying trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

I need to understand how to obtain $f/g$ and $f/h$ from the following equations:
$$
\frac{f^2\sin^2\alpha}{h^2}+\frac{f^2\cos^2\alpha}{g^2}=f^2/k^2
$$
$$
\frac{f^2\sin^2\beta}{h^2}+\frac{f^2\cos^2\beta}{g^2}=f^2/l^2
$$
Which must lead to the following expressions:
$$
(f/g)^2=\frac{(\frac{f\sin\alpha}{l}+\frac{f\sin\beta}{k})(\frac{f\sin\alpha}{l}-\frac{f\sin\beta}{k})}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha-\beta)}
$$
$$
(f/h)^2=\frac{(\frac{f\cos\beta}{k}+\frac{f\cos\alpha}{l})(\frac{f\cos\beta}{k}-\frac{f\cos\alpha}{l})}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha-\beta)}
$$
I know the expressions are correct but I get lost in the algebra and can't understand how to go from the first couple of equations to the second couple. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: But $f^2$ can be cancelled straightaway

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I notice is, both in the starting and ending expressions, you can divide both sides by $f^2$, so the variable $f$ plays no role in this calculation other than being along for the ride. Dividing it from the initial equations, we get:

$$
\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{h^2}+\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{g^2}=1/k^2
$$
$$
\frac{\sin^2\beta}{h^2}+\frac{\cos^2\beta}{g^2}=1/l^2
$$

Now, just to give us a break from fractions, let's define $H=\frac{1}{h^2}$, $G=\frac{1}{g^2}$, $K=\frac{1}{k^2}$, and $L=\frac{1}{l^2}$, giving us:

$$
H\sin^2\alpha + G\cos^2\alpha = K
$$
$$
H\sin^2\beta+G\cos^2\beta = L
$$

Now we see that we have linear equations with unknowns $H$ and $G$, and we can solve them by the usual techniques:

$$
H=\frac{K\cos^2\beta-L\cos^2\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\beta-\sin^2\beta\cos^2\alpha}
$$
$$
G=\frac{L\sin^2\alpha-K\sin^2\beta}{\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\beta-\sin^2\beta\cos^2\alpha}
$$

Undoing our substitution for $K$ and $L$, we note that both numerators are differences of two squares, and can be factored accordingly:

$$\begin{align}
K\cos^2\beta-L\cos^2\alpha = \frac{\cos^2\beta}{k^2}-\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{l^2} &= \left(\frac{\cos\beta}{k}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\cos\alpha}{l}\right)^2\\
&= \left(\frac{\cos\beta}{k}+\frac{\cos\alpha}{l}\right)\left(\frac{\cos\beta}{k}-\frac{\cos\alpha}{l}\right),
\end{align}$$

and similarly for the other one.

That just leaves the (identical) denominators to account for. They can also be factored as differences of two squares:

$$\begin{align}
\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\beta-\sin^2\beta\cos^2\alpha &= (\sin\alpha\cos\beta)^2 - (\sin\beta\cos\alpha)^2\\
&=(\sin\alpha\cos\beta + \sin\beta\cos\alpha)(\sin\alpha\cos\beta -
 \sin\beta\cos\alpha)\\
&=\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha-\beta),
\end{align}$$

where the last step uses the identities for $\sin$ of a sum and a difference.

Finally, multiply both sides by $f^2$ again, and you obtain your desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great help

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs is it possible that your first solution for $H$ has the wrong signs? I obtain: $H=\frac{-K\cos^2\beta+L\cos^2\alpha}{-\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\beta+\sin^2\beta\cos^2\alpha}$

Comment: That's the same answer. Just multiply by $\frac{-1}{-1}$

Comment: Yes, thanks, and sorry for bothering.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove common $f^2$ as having no role in problem.

You are asking to just to solve two linear equations with two unknowns.

Let $$ k_1=1/h^2,\, k_2=1/g^2,\, 1/k^2 = x_1,\, 1/l^2 = x_2,\,  $$

$$ k_1 \cos ^2 \alpha+ k_2 \sin^2 \alpha = x_1 \tag1$$
$$ k_1 \cos ^2 \beta+ k_2 \sin^2 \beta = x_2 \tag2  $$

By Cramer's Rule common denominator

$$ D= (\cos \alpha \sin \beta)^2- (\sin \alpha \cos \beta)^2 \tag3 $$

that simplify to common denominator in your last two equations.

and numerators for $k_1,k_2$ are respectively

$$  x_1 k_2 \sin^2 \beta - x_2 k_2 \sin ^2\alpha \tag4 $$

$$  x_2  k_1 \cos^2 \alpha - x_1  k_1 \cos^2\beta \tag5 $$

which again simplify to numerators you  gave in the last two equations after plugging in 1) and 2) for $x_1,x_2$.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about Cramer's rule so I used the technique of equating coefficients and could understand the results that @G Tony Jacobs also gave me.